# Height not returned from local storage when refreshing react grid layout

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, plotly.js, react-grid-layout

I am designing a dashboard UI in which users can create their own customisable dashboards with different visualisations using react-grid-layout. I have it so when users change the layout, it is saved into local storage. When the page is refreshed, the layout is returned. This is currently working, with the exception of height. When the user refreshes the page the width and position of the grid items are restored, however they are all rendered with a row height of 1 until an item is moved and then all the heights snapped back to their stored values. I can see that local storage values for height are all correct, so I'm not sure why the heights are not correct when it is refreshed.

Here is the code I am using:

```
const Dash = () => {
  //hook to determine when drag background shows
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = React.useState(false)

  //Variable used for id of grid component:
  const id = uuid()

  // Hook to set layout state
  const savedLayout = getLayout(username+1)  
 

  //column size is static
  //layouts taken from local storage via function
  const [ state, setState ] = React.useState({
    cols: { lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 },
    rowHeight: 30,
    layout: savedLayout
  })

  //function ammends layout array with additional grid item
  const addItem = () => { 
    console.log('adding: ' + id);
    const newLayout = state.layout;
    newLayout.push({
      i: `${id}`,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: 3,
      h: 3
    })
    setState({layout: newLayout})
  }

  //function to remove grid item on click
  const removeItem = (i) => {
    console.log(i)
    setState({ layout: _.reject(state.layout, { i:i }) })     
  }

   //function to calculate where to add items based on the cols
   const onBreakpointChange = (breakpoint, cols) => {
    setState({
      cols: cols,
      breakpoint: breakpoint
    })
    console.log(state)
  }

  //function to save layout to LS everytime a grid item is moved.
  const onLayoutChange = () => {
    saveLayout(username+1, state.layout)
    console.log(state.layout)
  }

  //When item is dropped, the dragbackground will disappear and
  //Layout state is updated
  const onMoveStop = (layout) => {
    setIsDragging(false);
    setState({ layout: layout })
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
      <Dragfield
        {...state}
        className="layout"
        onDragStart={() => setIsDragging(true)}
        onDragStop={(layouts) => onMoveStop(layouts)}
        onResizeStart={() => setIsDragging(true)}
        onResizeStop={(layouts) => onMoveStop(layouts)}
        isDragging={isDragging}
        breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
        onBreakpointChange={onBreakpointChange}
        onLayoutChange={() => onLayoutChange()}
        cols={{ lg: 12, md: 12, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
        resizeHandles={['se']}
        compactType={'vertical'}
        draggableHandle=".dragHandle"               
     >        
        {_.map(state.layout, (item, i) => (
          <div key={item.i} data-grid={state.layout[i]}>            
          <DashItem key={item.i}>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(item.i)}>Remove Item</button>  
            <CreateGraph data={state.layout[i]}/>
          </DashItem>
          <div className='dragHandle'>Drag From Here</div>
          </div>
      ))}
      </Dragfield>
    </div>
  );
}

//function to get user layout from LS
const getLayout = (key) => {
    try {
        const serialisedState = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (serialisedState === null) {
          return []
        }
        return JSON.parse(serialisedState);
    } catch (error) {
      return []
    }
}

//function to save user layout to LS
const saveLayout = ( layoutName, state) => {
    try {
        const serialisedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem(layoutName, serialisedState);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("local storage error")
    }
}

export default Dash;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a separate state for `cols`, `rowHeight` and `layout`.

When you're calling

```
setState({
  cols: cols,
  breakpoint: breakpoint
})
```

You're indirectly setting `layout` to `undefined`.

You should be doing this instead:

```
const [cols, setCols] = useState({ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 });
const [rowHeight, setRowHeight] = useState(30);
const [layout, setLayout] = useState(getLayout(username + 1));
```

Or if you prefer not to use separate states, you could do the following:

```
setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  cols: cols,
  breakpoint: breakpoint
}))
```

Comment: Your second suggestion should update the state using a callback. Like this:
setState((prevState) => ({..prevState, cols, breakpoint }))

Comment: Ahh great, that did the job, thanks very much